# Jquery Form validation using object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I working with form validation. My code is working fine but whenever I click on send button validations showing multiple time. And here I want to add radio button, checkbox, select according to my code. How should I add these other fields? I tried my level best but couldn't achieve it.
Can anyone help me to add this to other fields?
Below is my code:

```js
    var Validator = function(formObject) {
        this.form = $(formObject);

        var Elements = {
            name: {
                reg: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/,
                error: "Not a valid name.",
            },

            email: {
                reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i,
                error: "Not a valid e-mail address.",
            },

            message: {
                reg: /^(?!\s*$).+/,
                error: "Message field cannot be empty.",
            },
        };

        var handleError = function(element, message) {
            element.addClass('input-error');
            var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
            var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
            error.appendTo($err_msg);
            element.keyup(function() {
                $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    element.removeClass('input-error');
                });
            });

        };

        this.validate = function() {
          var errorCount = 0;
            this.form.find("input, textarea").each(function(index, field){
                var type = $(field).data("validation");
                var validation = Elements[type];
                if (validation){
                    if (!validation.reg.test($(field).val())){
                      errorCount++;
                        handleError($(field), validation.error);
                    }            
                }
            })
          return errorCount == 0;
        };
    };

    $(function(){
        $("form#test").on("submit", function(event){
            //event.preventDefault();
            return new Validator(this).validate(); // "this" here refers to the form
            
        })
    })
```

```css
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
        font: 76% Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    form {
        margin: 1em 0 0 2em;
        width: 90%;
    }

    fieldset {
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }

    legend {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }


    label {
        float: left;
        width: 5em;
        padding-right: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    div {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    input {
        font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    fieldset ul li input {
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    textarea {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    form p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.4em 0 0 7em;
    }

    form p input {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    div.error {
        clear: left;
        margin-left: 5.3em;
        color: red;
        padding-right: 1.3em;
        height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 0.3em;
        line-height: 1.3;
    }

    .input-error {
        background: #ff9;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="test">

    <fieldset>

    <legend>Contact information</legend>


    <div>
        <label for="name">Firstname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" data-validation="name" />
    </div>
     

    <div>
        <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" data-validation="name" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-validation="email"/>
        
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="15" data-validation="message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" /></p>

    </fieldset>


    </form>
```

Comment: When do you want to add controls? On button click?

Comment: @Ankita yeah on submit click.On one click showing errors and if i again click same error coming in all iteration multiple times the same error is showing.

Comment: I was asking about the controls(radiobutton, checkbox), which you want to add.

Comment: @Ankita I want to add them all (radio, checkbox and select) according to my requirement of the code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this codepen:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/BVNXYE

I have added this line

```
$err_msg.find('.error').remove();
```

Updated code:

```
var Validator = function(formObject) {
        this.form = $(formObject);

        var Elements = {
            name: {
                reg: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/,
                error: "Not a valid name.",
            },

            email: {
                reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i,
                error: "Not a valid e-mail address.",
            },

            message: {
                reg: /^(?!\s*$).+/,
                error: "Message field cannot be empty.",
            },
        };

        var handleError = function(element, message) {
            element.addClass('input-error');
            var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
            $err_msg.find('.error').remove();
            var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
            error.appendTo($err_msg);
            element.keyup(function() {
                $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    element.removeClass('input-error');
                });
            });

        };

        this.validate = function() {
                var errorCount = 0;
            this.form.find("input, textarea").each(function(index, field){
                var type = $(field).data("validation");
                var validation = Elements[type];
                if (validation){
                    if (!validation.reg.test($(field).val())){
                            errorCount++;
                        handleError($(field), validation.error);
                    }            
                }
            })
                return errorCount == 0;
        };
    };

    $(function(){
        $("form#test").on("submit", function(event){
            //event.preventDefault();
            return new Validator(this).validate(); // "this" here refers to the form

        })
    })
```

Comment: As the following answer by @Arvind `checkbox` and `radio` are being validated but according to my requirement, I want that to be done object-oriented. And I also want select option. This is the last thing im lagging with. I will be pleased if you help me out with this. Comment if any you need any clarification.

Comment: here `email` is not validated correctly. if i type any character it is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever I click on send button validations showing multiple time

```
$err_msg.empty(); /* add this cleanup old errors */
error.appendTo($err_msg);
```

Comment: yeah, I added before but it's not working. error text is not showing but some space is added to each iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(function() 
    {
        jQuery("#test").validate({
            rules:
               {
                "firstname":
                    {
                        required: true
                    },
                "lastname":
                    {
                        required: true
                    },
                "email":
                    {
                        required: true
                    },
                "message":
                    {
                        required: true
                    }
               }
    });
});
```

Comment: this should be enough for validation

Comment: i'm not using jquery validate plugin.